Which statistical approach is best for diverse conversion rates in a controlled experiment?
Our software startup builds chat bots for ecommerce websites. The chatbot talks to customers that open the chat bot, and has the goal of closing the sale with the store’s main product. We have about 100 active ecommerce stores using our chat bot. Chat bot conversations either result in a sale or don’t, so the metric we are optimizing for is the conversion rate for each store.
We want to run A/B tests on the chat bot across all stores to measure improvements in conversion rate. Our goal is to introduce changes that maximize conversion rate as a whole across all types of stores (big/small, no matter what product category).
Here are the main considerations that make our scenario tricky:

Each store has a different intrinsic conversion rate since our stores are of all types of categories and have different customer demographics

We only have 100 active stores, which is a rather small sample size. However, across all 100 stores, we have about 300k unique user conversations weekly, about 10k of those conversations convert

Stores vary drastically in weekly conversations and conversion rate. Some stores have 50k conversations a week, others may only have 1k a week. Average and median weekly conversations per store is 2000 and 230 respectively.

We want to make changes in our chat bot that positively affect all stores


What would be the best approach for this? Hierarchical modeling? Bayesian? Frequentist? Or something special?
